# How to convert all ps files in a directory to pdf using one ps2pdf command?

Tags: linux, shell, pdf

For one of my classes I need to save a bunch of memory dumps and assembler listings from a simulator.  The professor suggests using `enscript` to convert the files to `.ps` then `ps2pdf` to convert them to `.pdf`. This can get tiresome when there are >10 files I need to do this for.  Is there an efficient way to do this with one `ps2pdf` command (and possibly one use of `enscript`)?

I know wildcards exist, and I've tried to use them. I'm having trouble figuring out how to use them with `ps2pdf`. One thing I've tried is `ps2pdf *.ps *.pdf`, but that has not worked.

What I'm looking for is a way to convert all of the files to `.ps` then to `.pdf` with a couple quick commands so I can tar them up and `scp` them to my local machine for printing.

Comment: Please show some sample `enscript` commands you use.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
for f in *.ps; do
  ps2pdf "$f" "${f%.*}.pdf"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`find *.ps -maxdepth 0 -type f | xargs -I{} sh -c 'ps2pdf "$1" "${1%.ps}.pdf"' -- {}`

- find get files those ending with `.ps`, and regular files `-type f`, `-maxdepth 0` only required if there is sub directories that contain `.ps` files that you don't want to be affected.
- xargs execute a shell script once for each file, passing filename as a parameter `{}`, `--` is required to prevent further option processing.
- sh -c execute string inside single quotes `'...'`, $1 will hold the filename, because we passed that as first parameter to it.
- `${1%.ps}.pdf` will remove the `.ps` extension from the filename and add `.pdf` to it.

You did not provided example for `enscript` you use, so I cannot tell you for sure, this will work or not for that.

Comment: `find *.ps` does not look hopeful - have you tried it? How about `find . -name "*.ps"`

Comment: I did try it, and worked. but you right about that it is safer to use `find . -name "*.ps"` @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0):

Until you show how your assembler and memory dumps are named and how you use `enscript` to convert them to Postscript files, I can only show you the way to convert your Postscript files to PDFs.

IMHO, if you have lots of Postscript files to convert to PDFs, you should use **GNU Parallel** and get them all done fast, and simply, in parallel like this:

```
parallel --dry-run ps2pdf {} {.}.pdf ::: *.ps
```

**Sample Output**

```
ps2pdf a.ps a.pdf
ps2pdf b.ps b.pdf
```

If you show how your assembly and dump files are named, I can show you a better way of achieving your goal - maybe you can define a function or a script that does everything nice and fast in parallel for nearly zero typing effort...